# Programatically create directory for new user on web site

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, permissions, create-directory

I just uploaded my site to Go Daddy and have code that creates a directory dynamically based on a user id when the user creates an account on my site. It's not creating the directory so I suppose I need to set permissions in some way but I don't have control over IIS since my site's being hosted. How do I programatically set permissions?

```
if(Directory.Exists(path))
                return true;

try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: What is the exception handler doing?  (You do have an exception handler right?).  If CreateDirectory fails, you should get an exception message.

Comment: @Steve I'm guessing the handler looks like this, between the parenthesis: (*yummy exception*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file/sub directory only within the root web directory provided to your website.
And GoDaddy might have provided you a login to a control panel using which you can set permissions in your directory. 
The following is the process to set up permissions on a godaddy account:

> 1. Login using your user name/account number and password
> 2. Click on My Account
> 3. Click on Hosting Account List
> 4. Click on Open (the web hosting package you want to open)
> 5. Scroll down to content and click File Manager
> 6. Select the domain folder you want to set permissions for and click permissions button on the upper control bar
> 7. Set the required permissions and click OK.

Comment: Yep that was it. I should have thought about that! Thanks.

Comment: I had to go into the Hosting account for the domain (Plesk), and then change permissions under `Virtual Directories`.  Use the `Directory Access Permissions` located at the top under `Virtual Directories`

Answer (score 0):

Where you have the path variable, have you tried:

```
if(Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
    return true;

try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path));
}
```

What is the format of path?

Comment: I have a directory named people that I created on the server so when I pass path as a parameter to my method, I have already called Server.MapPath("people"); I think it might be a permissions issue on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the physical directory path using [Server.MapPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(path);       

if(Directory.Exists(directoryPath)) 
            return true; 

try 
{ 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath ); 
}
```

On the web server you can't create a directory or file outside your website `virtual directory` folder.

Comment: I have a directory named people that I created on the server so when I pass path as a parameter to my method, I have already called Server.MapPath("people"); I think it might be a permissions issue on the directory.