# Not able to create directory at runtime in live website using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have godaddy server account, I want to create a directory on my website location at runtime  and I am using the code given below to create directory.

`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);`

But `500 internal server` error is displaying.

Comment: You're not trying to create a folder on the client, are you?

Comment: I did not understand. What are you asking.

Comment: Server, client? You can't create folders on the client, only on your server.

Comment: I have godaddy server and want to add directory at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific ASP User will need permission on the parent folder to create new folders.  The User could be IIS_USERS, IUSR, ASP_NET or similar...

EDIT: Extra detail, 
On the server - where you are trying to create a folder (the Parent folder) - Right Click and bring up the Security window.  In this window you want to Add 'Modify' (or 'Full Control') for the IIS User. (Use the ADD button to add the IIS_USERS first, then ensure that ALLOW is ticked for Full Control) It is probably called IIS_USERS but you can check this depending on your system.  The User will NOT have permission by default.

See this re GoDaddy [Programatically create directory for new user on web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407437/programatically-create-directory-for-new-user-on-web-site)

Comment: I am new to asp.net so can you please explain.

Comment: I am using godaddy server, Can you please guide me.?

Comment: You will need to contact their support. Also make sure you are trying to create a folder in the Public or www branch...(Not in the restricted areas - if they have any)

Comment: The GoDaddy server was totally relevant, this should be in your Question detail so that others know what you are talking about.  Otherwise your question will be ignored.  You can edit your question